# When a new picture is placed in a windows directory, automatically send the picture via email

Tags: windows, file, email, automation, new-operator

I'm trying to find a solution to automatically send an email each time a new picture is placed in a folder.

Example:
C:\newpics\

When I add a new file in that folder, let's say newimage.bmp
the file 'newimage.bmp' should automatically send to myemail@example.org

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating an Outlook add-in where you may track for particular folder changes and send email automatically.

Use [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) can be used to watch for changes in a specified directory. You can watch for changes in files and subdirectories of the specified directory. You can create a component to watch files on a local computer, a network drive, or a remote computer.

To watch for changes in all files, set the Filter property to an empty string ("") or use wildcards ("*.*"). To watch a specific file, set the Filter property to the file name. For example, to watch for changes in the file MyDoc.txt, set the Filter property to "MyDoc.txt". You can also watch for changes in a certain type of file. For example, to watch for changes in text files, set the `Filter` property to "*.txt".

There are several types of changes you can watch for in a directory or file. For example, you can watch for changes in `Attributes`, the `LastWrite` date and time, or the Size of files or directories. This is done by setting the `NotifyFilter` property to one of the `NotifyFilters` values. For more information on the type of changes you can watch, see `NotifyFilters`.

You can watch for renaming, deletion, or creation of files or directories. For example, to watch for renaming of text files, set the Filter property to "*.txt" and call the `WaitForChanged` method with a `Renamed` specified for its parameter.

See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20Outlook%20project%20in%20Visual%20Studio&text=In%20the%20templates%20pane%2C%20expand,Outlook%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project.) to get started quickly.